# Find the common element with the highest index

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to refactor a piece of code in a less verbose methods.

Basically I have this array of user skills:

```
const skills = ['add', 'edit', 'delete', 'secondSkill', 'fourthSkill']
```

Then I have an array of select options:

```
const options = [
  {
    label: "First",
    value: "firstSkill"
  },
  {
    label: "Second",
    value: "secondSkill"
  },
  {
    label: "Third",
    value: "thirdSkill"
  },
  {
    label: "Fourth",
    value: "fourthSkill"
  }
];
```

I'm trying to write a method that:

- find the common elements between arrays **skills** and **options**
- return ONLY the common element with the biggest index in the options array

For example: in this case I want to return **fourthSkill** because is the element with the biggest index in my options array.

I came up with something like that:

```
const findDefaultValue = (selectOptions, userSkills) => {
  const commonItems = selectOptions.filter((opt) =>
    userSkills.includes(opt.value)
  );
  
  const findIndexes = commonItems.map((item) => {
    return selectOptions.indexOf(item);
  });
  const maxIndex = Math.max(...findIndexes);
  return options[maxIndex];
};
```

It kinda works, but I would like to hear from you if there are shorter ways to do it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can just return the last item of `commonItems`, like:

```
const findDefaultValue = (selectOptions, userSkills) => {
  const commonItems = selectOptions.filter((opt) =>
    userSkills.includes(opt.value)
  );
  
  return commonItems.at(-1);
}
```

---

In the future, you'll be able to use [`findLast`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), like:

```
const findDefaultValue = (selectOptions, userSkills) => {
  return selectOptions.findLast((opt) =>
    userSkills.includes(opt.value)
  );
};
```

Comment: Great thanks. Is not a problem if the skills array would be ['add', 'edit', 'fourthSkill', 'secondSkill"], with the order that doesn't follow the options indexes?

Comment: no, the order of the filtered array is based on the order of the array being filtered, not the array being tested against.

Answer (score 1):

Since the particular index is not important, and all you need is just one element, you can iterate through a reversed copy of the array and return the first element that matches.

```js
const skills = ['add', 'edit', 'delete', 'secondSkill', 'fourthSkill']
const options = [{label: "First",value: "firstSkill"}, {label: "Second",value: "secondSkill"}, {label: "Third", value: "thirdSkill"}, {label: "Fourth",value: "fourthSkill"}];

const findDefaultValue = (selectOptions, userSkills) => {
    for(const {label, value} of [...selectOptions].reverse()) {
        if( userSkills.includes(value) ) {
            return {label,value};
        }
    }
    return 'NONE FOUND';
};

console.log( findDefaultValue(options, skills) );
/*OUTPUT:
{
  "label": "Fourth",
  "value": "fourthSkill"
}
*/
```

Alternatively, you can use @AlexandrBelan's one-liner with the caveat of using a copy, so `options` remains unchanged:

```js
const skills = ['add', 'edit', 'delete', 'secondSkill', 'fourthSkill']
const options = [{label: "First",value: "firstSkill"}, {label: "Second",value: "secondSkill"}, {label: "Third", value: "thirdSkill"}, {label: "Fourth",value: "fourthSkill"}];

const findDefaultValue = 
    (selectOptions, userSkills) => 
    [...selectOptions].reverse().find(({value}) => userSkills.includes(value));

console.log( findDefaultValue(options, skills) );
/*OUTPUT:
{
  "label": "Fourth",
  "value": "fourthSkill"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one solution. One-liner if you don't mind.

```js
const skills = ['add', 'edit', 'delete', 'secondSkill', 'fourthSkill']
const options = [{label: "First",value: "firstSkill"}, {label: "Second",value: "secondSkill"}, {label: "Third", value: "thirdSkill"}, {label: "Fourth",value: "fourthSkill"}];

const result = options.reverse().find(({ value }) => skills.includes(value));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve it with a single line of code by using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [Array.at(-1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) methods of JavaScript.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const skills = ['add', 'edit', 'delete', 'secondSkill', 'fourthSkill'];

const options = [
  {
    label: "First",
    value: "firstSkill"
  },
  {
    label: "Second",
    value: "secondSkill"
  },
  {
    label: "Third",
    value: "thirdSkill"
  },
  {
    label: "Fourth",
    value: "fourthSkill"
  }
];

const res = options.filter(obj => skills.includes(obj.value)).at(-1);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce`, in one pass and one liner

```js
const findDefaultValue = (options, skills) =>
  options.reduce(
    (last, item) => (skills.includes(item.value) ? item : last),
    null
  );
  
const skills = ['add', 'edit', 'delete', 'secondSkill', 'fourthSkill']
const options = [{label: "First",value: "firstSkill"}, {label: "Second",value: "secondSkill"}, {label: "Third", value: "thirdSkill"}, {label: "Fourth",value: "fourthSkill"}];


console.log(findDefaultValue(options, skills));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```